# .load() method in jquery give me 404 - Not Found error

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a simple page that I need to load .html file to a DIV ,but I always have 404 NOT FOUND

I have a file called demo_test.txt in the same folder of my JSP file,I need to load this file to the div with ID="div1"

here is the code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
   // $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt");
   $("#div1").load("demo_test.txt", function(responseText, statusText, xhr)
        {
                if(statusText == "success")
                        alert("Successfully loaded the content!");
                if(statusText == "error")
                        alert("An error occurred: " + xhr.status + " - " + xhr.statusText);
        });

  });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried to browse the file using the url where you expect to find it?

Comment: Did you check in the network inspector tab of your browser debugger which file it's trying to load? And then hit right click and 'Open in new tab' on it?

Comment: In order for this to work, the file must be in the exact same directory as the HTML page calling the script. Is this the case?

Comment: yes it is in the same folder of the jsp page

Answer (score 1):

Like  Claudio Redi said...

you're trying to load a file relative to the path you are at. Try hard coding the file path and then viewing it your browser and then it should load.

so your line will be like this  (if file is located in WEBROOT /MY_APP/Files)

```
$("#div1").load("/MY_APP/Files/demo_test.txt", function(responseText, statusText, xhr)
```

or the full path

```
$("#div1").load("http://MyWebsite.com/MY_APP/Files/demo_test.txt", function(responseText, statusText, xhr)
```

Comment: demo_test.txt and the jsp page both in the folder : web pages\WEB-INF\jsp so please how I should write the url

Comment: I used this url "http://localhost:8080/RSS/WEB-INF/jsp/htmlForm.html" and it still not working

Comment: try putting // in front of it, this will take from http when you are non-secure and https when you are.. so this:

$("#div1").load("//localhost:8080/RSS/WEB-INF/jsp/htmlForm.html", function(responseText, statusText, xhr)