# AJAX Load not working Error occured: 404 error

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

This is my code and I'm trying to load html from demo_test.txt into it, but it won't work no matter what I try. I've tried changing it from txt to html as well and it still won't load.
The other ajax command such as appending the text works correctly its the load line which won't work?

```
<head>
    <title>Flask AJAX Demo</title>
    <!--<link rel=stylesheet type=text/css href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style2.css') }}"> -->

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <script type=text/javascript
      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type=text/javascript>
      var $SCRIPT_ROOT = {{ request.script_root|tojson|safe }};
    </script>
```

```
    <script type=text/javascript>
  $(function() {
$("#submitBtn").click(function() {
    $('#div1').load('dem_test.txt');
     $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: $SCRIPT_ROOT + "/echo/",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: { echoValue: $('input[name="echoText"]').val() },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#echoResult').append("<br>");
            $('#echoResult').append(data.value);
            
        }
    });     
});
  });

</script>
<strong>Enter a value to echo back:</strong>
<input type='text' size='10' id='echoText' name='echoText'>
<button type='button' id='submitBtn' name='submitBtn'>Submit via AJAX</button><br /><br />
<strong><div id='echoResult'></div></strong>
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
```

This is what is in the demo_test.txt, this won't work if it is html either

```
<h2>jQuery and AJAX is FUN!!!</h2>
<p id="p1">This is some text in a paragraph.</p>
```

#### EDIT:

I changed my load to this:

```
$('#div1').load('dem_test.txt', function(response, status, xhr) {
if ( status == "error" ) {
    alert("Error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
} else {
    alert("Text loaded!");
}

});
```

But I get Error occured: 404 error , but the dem_test.txt file is in the same folder as the html file?

#### EDIT 2

I have tried this exact example as well found here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944723/load-method-in-jquery-give-me-404-not-found-error
BUT it won't work like his didn't either, what should the file location be?

Comment: Your file is HTML, but you've told the ajax call that you're loading `application/json`.  That probably causes a problem (like an error trying to parse the JSON that isn't JSON).  I'd suggest that you look for errors in both the error console and by adding an `error: ` callback handler.

Comment: Make sure your `url` is correct in `$('#div1').load('dem_test.txt');`, check the browser's console if there is any error.

Comment: application/json is for the other part im doing, the load call is before i even call that

Comment: if i delete the entire $.ajax part it still won't work

Comment: The other ajax command in that function are working thats why I don't understand why load won't work because ive tried many examples ive found online and load won't work?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use jquery load in this way;

```
$('#div1').load('dem_test.txt', function(response, status, xhr) {
    if ( status == "error" ) {
        alert("Error occured: " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText );
    } else {
        alert("Text loaded!");
    }

});
```

You can see alert if file is loaded

Comment: I get Error occured: 404 error everytime...does that mean my dem_test.txt is not in the correct location? because its in the same folder as this html file?

Comment: Yes, it's not there as I already asked you to check for it in the comment.

Comment: If I go to file:///Users/Varun/Desktop/flask/templates/demo_test.txt it shows up correctly, but when I try loading it "//demo_test.txt" I get "0 error" what does that mean?

Comment: You need to serve that file on web server. For example put it on a server and reach it via `www.yourserver.com/dem_test.txt`