# jquery ajax method .load() give error 404

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I found similar question [ajax jquery .load() error 404](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16944723/load-method-in-jquery-give-me-404-not-found-error) but I can't solve this problem.
This is my jsp file

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
    href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/admincss.css">

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("#div1").load("http://localhost:8080/CarRent/WebContent/pages/demo_test.txt", function(responseTxt, statusTxt, xhr){
            if(statusTxt == "success")
                alert("External content loaded successfully!");
            if(statusTxt == "error")
                alert("Error: " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText);
        });
    });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<button>Get External Content</button>
</body>
</html>
```

and this a structure of my program[image]
Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you paste http://localhost:8080/CarRent/WebContent/pages/demo_test.txt into your web browser do you get a 404?  Or do you get content?

Comment: As the question you linked to clearly shows, this is most likely an issue with the url being incorrect. If you go to `http://localhost:8080/CarRent/WebContent/pages/demo_test.txt` in your web browser do you get the correct output?

Comment: Yes, I also have NOT found

Comment: Maybe I must add something to web xml file ?